# Cosa significa "incidere un disco" in questo contesto?

Tags: meaning

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Sul tavolo troneggia una tromba. Geremia gira un gancio. Vita sobbalza, perché Enrico Caruso le ha strillato nell’orecchio. Tutti ridono della sua faccia stupefatta. Diamante si impietosisce e la informa che Enrico Caruso è nascosto nella tromba. Cioè, non proprio nella tromba, su un piatto nero dove è disegnato un angelo che **incide un disco** con la piuma della sua ala. Sotto la tromba c’è una scatola di legno. La scatola è un fonografo, e d’ora in poi in questa casa ci sarà musica tutto il giorno.

Sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/incidere2) ho trovato che "incidere" può avere questo significato:

> Eseguire, con particolari tecniche, la registrazione di suoni, voci e sim. su appropriati supporti; è usato sia con riferimento a chi compie il processo tecnico dell’incisione: *i. una canzone, un’opera, un discorso; una casa discografica che l’anno scorso ha inciso più di un milione di dischi*; sia al cantante, al musicista, all’attore e sim. che eseguono ciò che forma il contenuto dell’incisione stessa: *un cantautore che ha inciso molti CD; la 3a Sinfonia di Beethoven incisa da Toscanini*.

Tuttavia, non riesco a capire cosa stava facendo l'angelo sul disegno di cui si parla nel brano sopra citato. Faceva qualcosa con la piuma della sua ala per registrare suoni su un disco? Produceva suoni con questa piuma e qualcuno li registrava per produrre un disco?

Comment: Si riferirà a questo (l'immagine più a sinistra delle quattro)? http://www.likesx.com/dischi-78-giri-per-grammofono-lirica-inni-canz/ Se sì, il fatto che impugni la piuma come... una penna, avvalora il fatto che stia incidendo e non riproducendo.

Comment: Hai ragione, @DaG! Più concretamente, molto probabilmente si riferisce a un disco simile a [questo](http://www.45worlds.com/78rpm/record/052120uk) o a [quest'altro](https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/RARE-1909-Enrico-Caruso-IDEALE-Tosti-GRAMOPHONE-MONARCH-RECORD-052154-/263129316237).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Incidere un disco" significa prepararlo per essere ascoltato come nella definizione Treccani.
L'angelo sta "incidendo" sul disco le tracce che poi potranno essere ascoltate.

Molto probabilmente il brano si riferisce a un disco simile a quello che si può vedere in questa immagine:

[image: Disco Caruso]

Immagine tratta da questa [fonte](https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/RARE-1909-Enrico-Caruso-IDEALE-Tosti-GRAMOPHONE-MONARCH-RECORD-052154-/263129316237).

L'immagine dell'angelo si può vedere un po' meglio su quest'altra fotografia:

[image]

Immagine tratta da questa [fonte](http://www.likesx.com/dischi-78-giri-per-grammofono-lirica-inni-canz/).

Come segnalato da @DaG, il fatto che l'angelo impugni la piuma come si fa con una penna per scrivere evoca l'idea che sta registrando la musica sul disco.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE! Quindi, l'angelo stava creando tracce sulla superficie del disco per registrare suoni?

Comment: Grazie. Corretto: l'angelo con la sua piuma fa il moto di incidere il disco. Potrebbe essere la grafica di un marchio di grammofoni.

Comment: E questo come si può capire da un disegno? Non riesco a immaginarlo.

Comment: Ciao. Immaginati che l'ala dell'angelo sia la puntina di un giradischi o di un grammofono (immagine https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71ZTRi1TdAL._SY679_.jpg) . Anche se il processo di "stampa" attuale dei dischi in vinile non è fatto con una "punta", l'immagine dell'angelo richiama questo concetto

Comment: Sì, ma se io vedessi tale immagine, penserei che l'angelo stesse facendo suonare il disco come se fosse un grammofono o un giradischi e non che stesse registrando suoni sul disco.

Comment: Hai ragione. In effetti sarebbe anche più logico: la piuma agendo come una puntina fa sì che l'angelo canti. Però il senso di incidere potrebbe anche essere quello dell'entrare della puntina nel solco del disco (e quindi non dell'incidere un disco). La puntina è un pò come uno scalpello.

Comment: È precisamente per questa ragione che ho chiesto la domanda: non mi era chiaro se "incidere" potesse avere in questo contesto un senso diverso da quello di "registrare suoni".

Comment: Sì, mi sembra corretto

Comment: Finalmente, avevi ragione: vedendo le immagini dei dischi si capisce bene.